# How to release/free IntPtr to function pointer?

Tags: c#, native, release, free, intptr

I've got native DLL (without sources) with two extern methods: `Init` and `DoSomeWork`.

Here is my class-wrapper:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
[DllImport(@"myDLL.dll",
SetLastError = true,
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
EntryPoint = "EntryPoint#1",
ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr InitNative();

[DllImport(@"myDLL.dll",
SetLastError = true,
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
EntryPoint = "EntryPoint#2",
ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern ushort DoSomeWorkN(byte[] arrayOut, [In] IntPtr initHandle);

private readonly IntPtr _initHandle;

public MyClass()
{
    _initHandle = InitNative();
}

protected override byte[] DoSomeWork()
{ 
  ...
    DoSomeWorkN(buffOut, _initHandle);
  ...
}

public override void Dispose()
{
    //???
}
```

I've tried:

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_initHandle); //throws exception: Invalid access to memory location. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E6)"}
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(_initHandle); //throws Access violation exception
Marshal.FreeBSTR(_initHandle); //doesn't throw exception, but doesn't work (after calling that method IntPtr isn't IntPtr.Zero)
```

So, how to implement correct disposing of _initHandle?

Comment: How would we know, it's your big secret library.

Comment: Also seems a bit strange to pull something native to the managed side... only to pass it back to the native side.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 No, it is a common pattern... Let's say you use a CreateFile Win32 api... It returns an handle to the opened file... You use WriteFile to write to it (using the handle), then CloseHandle to close it. In general, if you can imagine that the library isn't composed only of static methods, then the `this` must be kept somewhere :-)

Comment: @xanatos Of course, you would wrap that handle in a managed object, e.g. `SafeFileHandle` in your example. And of course, you need to specify who is the owner of that handle - it might be your code, or the library's.

Comment: @Luaan I don't comprehend how your comment is connected to mine. I was commenting the `Also seems a bit strange to pull something native to the managed side... only to pass it back to the native side`. How to handle in a *safe* way an unmanaged handle is something that we aren't speaking about

Comment: @xanatos Well, you were talking about the patterns used in .NET - and the BCL always uses safe managed wrappers for handles. This is always a good idea, because it makes finalization a lot simpler. Or would you just use the `IntPtr` from `CreateFile` directly?

Comment: @Luaan `CreateFile` was an example of a method that returns an opaque handle, that can only be used with its "family" of functions/methods. Other classical examples are all the methods to handle a device context, like `GetDC `(that returns HDC). He told `Also seems a bit strange to pull something native to the managed side... only to pass it back to the native side`, I showed an "Official" (of Microsoft) group of methods that do exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your library *should*/***must*** give you a third method:

```
void Free(IntPtr handle);
```

You can't know how the memory was allocated. If the memory was allocated through C `malloc` you can't even easily free it. Even worse, if it is a C++ object, only C++ can correctly deallocate it (calling the correct destructors). It must be the library to give you a method to free its memory.

(technically you can't even know what the IntPtr is :-) Perhaps it isn't really a pointer. It could be a number and you don't have to free anything... or it could be an `HANDLE` returned by Win32 `CreateFile`)

Comment: If there'd be such method, I'd use it, but there's no.

Comment: @redmanmale Then you have a problem that you can't solve :-) You have two options: A) if you call Init only once, then there is little to no problem. The memory will be freed at the end of the program, or B) call the writer of the library. Technically there is the possibility that `DoSomeWorkN` frees the allocated memory, but if you can call it multiple times for a single `Init`, then this isn't true

Comment: **xanatos** Writer insn't available. And yes, `Init` method called only once. So thank you.