# Use Marshal.FreeHGlobal() to free array that was previously allocated with "new" on the native side?

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, marshalling

If a dynamic array is allocated with

```
intPtr = new int[1234];
```

in c++ and the data is subsequently marshaled to a managed C# array, is it valid to free the originally allocated memory on the managed side using

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal()
```

or will this leak memory?

If this does leak memory, is there another method that can be used on the managed side to cleanly free the memory or is it necessary to implement the freeing code on the native side and pass a callback function to the managed side?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: you'll only do damage and won't free anything. You'll need to free the memory C++ side.

Comment: See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29077711/613130, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18172997/613130

Comment: Apples and oranges. Memory that was allocated via `new` in c++ Windows has nothing to do with the `GlobalFree/Heapxxxxx` functions in the Win32 API.  You shouldn't even mix the two on the c/c++ side.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34326909/585968

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `free`/`delete` from C#. You have to do it C/C++ side (the `new`/`malloc` by default use a "private" C/C++ allocator). The correct way to do it is to expose a `Free(IntPtr)` method in the C/C++ library, OR only use a shared allocator (but note that if you want the C++ destructor to be called on freeing of the memory, then you have to do the `delete` in C++)

Clearly in C/C++ you can use [`LocalAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/aa366723.aspx) to allocate memory and then in C# you can use `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()`, but then we are in the *OR only use a shared allocator* case (and you still have the problem that you can't call the C++ destructor from C#)